What's the difference between :focus-within and :has(:focus)?
I noticed recently that :focus-within can be entirely replaced with :has(:focus). What I find interesting is that they were both added in Level 4 of specification, so is there a difference between the two that I missed?
Reading MDN, I found one difference where :focus-within should work on the shadow dom elements, a direct quote: "This includes descendants in shadow trees", but I can't seem to get that to work.
The actual specification, backs my testing, as it says "The ... pseudo-class applies to ..., as well as element (or pseudo-element) whose descendant in the flat tree (including non-element nodes, such as text nodes) matches the conditions for matching :focus.", which directly contradicts MDN (as there is no mention of the shadow tree).
One actual difference I've found is :focus-within, also includes the element you're focusing on. But "within" implies "children elements", not "current element & its children". If you need it to match "current element & its children", you could use &:focus, &:has(:focus) (could also use :is() if you're not CSS nesting). Which would make more logical/linguistic sentence than :focus-within.
Example:
An example of using :focus-within, and sample code of how :has(:focus) can entirely replace it would be the awesome accessibility feature "Skip to Main content".
HTML: <div class="skip-link">Skip to <a href='#main'>content</a> or <a href='#footer'>footer</a></div>
CSS (:focus-within):
.skip-link {
  transform: translateY(-100%);

  &:focus-within {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

CSS (:has(:focus)):
.skip-link {
  transform: translateY(-100%);

  &:has(:focus) {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

Are there any other differences between the two?

There are always different ways to achieve the same thing using CSS. This doesn't imply we should deprecate one of them.

One difference is browser support. Firefox added support for :has in v121, and Firefox ESR is still on v115.


I noticed recently that :focus-within can be entirely replaced with :has(:focus)

But that contradicts your:

One actual difference I've found is :focus-within, also includes the element you're focusing on. But "within" implies "children elements", not "current element & its children". If you need it to match "current element & its children", you could use &:focus, &:has(:focus)

So :focus-within and :has(:focus) are not identical.
So why to use :focus-within instead of &:focus, &:has(:focus), which depends entirely on your use-case (leaving the slight performance differences aside), you can see :focus-within as a shorthand like logical properties or that you can just write border: 1px solid red instead of writing border-color, border-width, ...
:focus-within will also affect the element that has the focus.


input:focus-within {
  color: red;
}
<input value="test">



:has(:focus) only affects ascendants of the focused element.


input:has(:focus) {
  color: red;
}
<input value="test">




Yes, first part was more of context for the question and not like a factual statement, so yes I do contradict it after I partially answer my own question - I was looking for more differences, that can explain why one would use :focus-within over :has(:focus). But, "you could use :focus-within as a shorthand" I'd say would make enough sense to not just deprecate the pseudo-class, I can see it being used like that by quite a lot of people. So, thanks!
